# What is the physical difference of a symmetric and antisymmetric state superposition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I am inclined to think that the symmetric superposition implies that both states have the same global phase and that in the antisymmetric one they are completely dephased. By symmetric and antisymmetric superposition I mean the $S_z = 0$ triplet and singlet states (respectively), for example.

Comment: What do you mean by "physical difference"? They are *different* states, what exactly their different properties are depends on which states you superpose.

Comment: They are different states that originate from the same states, I want to understand how exactly the difference come to be. I'm not interested in the different properties of both superpositions, but on the physical (not mathematical, that I understand) reason there are two of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone has a problem with the physics behind the singlet and triplet, I have found an answer for my question.

The main problem I had was trying to give a meaning for the $ \left|\downarrow\uparrow \right\rangle $ state, as it was the "difference" between the singlet and triplet states. But I couldn't imagine one, as its difference to the $ \left|\uparrow\downarrow \right\rangle $ state (if treating with two electrons) shouldn't exist, given the indistinguishable nature of elementary particles.

Then I realized that these states, indeed, didn't give any meaning to the singlet and triplet, in fact, it was the other way around!

The singlet and triplet states are the true pure states, as they are eingenstates of the $S^2$ operator, and hence the $ \left|\downarrow\uparrow \right\rangle $ and $ \left|\uparrow\downarrow \right\rangle $ states are the superpositions of these pure states. Both give $ 50\% $ chance of collapse into one of the pure states: they are indeed the "same thing".

In the end, what gives the state an actual meaning is the value of measurement.